# Add string to an Array without Exception

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

Im trying to add the line `Smith B 55` to an array

```
            String line = bufRdr.readLine();
            if (line != null && !line.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
            for (s = 0; s < 3; ) {
                for (String word : line.split(" ")) {
                    singleMarkArray[s] = word;
                    s++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(singleMarkArray));
```

Why is this if statement causing the program to hang?

Without the check I get an java.lang.nullPointerException

Thanks for any help!

Comment: the if statement is not causing the program to hang. it's something else. maybe debug your program?

Comment: Hint: what do you think happens with `s` when `line.split(" ").length == 1`? And how will it impact on your outer loop?

Comment: Or to be more specific, move s++ to the outer loop.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need the `for` and the `for each` loops? 
You want to split the line in words and put these words in the array `singleMarkArray`, right?
You can do it this way:

```
String line = bufRdr.readLine();
if (line != null && !line.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
    singleMarkArray = line.split("\\s+");
    // the above line checks for multiple spaces
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(singleMarkArray));
}
```

So you don't have to worry about the size of `singleMarkArray` not being equal to the number of words.
Also your logic is wrong. 
You use a variable `s` as the counter of the `for` loop and you increase it inside the `for each` loop so its value is **undetermined** since you don't know the number of words.
As for the `java.lang.nullPointerException` you get, this happens when there are no more lines to read so this:

```
line = bufRdr.readLine();
```

will assign `null` to `line`.
This is why you always need to check after `readLine()`:

```
if (line != null...) {...}
```

Comment: Thank you Forpas for the detailed explanation, thats really helped me understand what I was doing wrong :)

Comment: This is even better than solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

fix your outer for loop :

```
for (s = 0; s < 3; s++ ) {
   for (String word : line.split(" ")) {
       singleMarkArray[s] = word;
   }
}
```

Comment: If s were to be incremented inside the inner loop, there may be an error due to `s` incrementing way to many times, above 3.